# Thymeleaf две кнопки в одной форме

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Проект на Spring-Boot + Thymeleaf
Вот html код:

```html
<form id="02" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/people/edit/{id}(id=${people.getId()})}" th:object="${people}">
    <div class="form-group mt-1">
        <label for="inp">Номер</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inp" placeholder="Введите имя" th:field="*{name}" autofocus required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Удалить</button>
</form>
```

Можно как-то в контроллере обработать события от этих двух кнопок?
Как правильно это делается?
Т.е. все в одной форме или для второй кнопки создается вторая форма?

Comment: JS. Но лучше в другой форме

Comment: Обычно это делается в двух разных формах, которые ведут на разные методы.